# uploading file using ashx filehandler and ajax always return error

Tags: jquery, .net, file-upload, webforms, ashx

I am using jquery-file-upload from blueimp (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

I have FileHandler.ashx for file uploads.

I am not able to return correct response from file handler. On javascript side, it always receives error. Please, guide me.

**// File handler (FileHandler.ashx)**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fname = String.Empty;
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];                    
                fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/UserImageUploads/" + file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(fname);
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    }
```

**// javascript part:**

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'FileHandler.ashx';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {

        },
        fail: function (e, data) {

        },
    });
});
```

The resut is always "fail" and never "success". Error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token C`.
This is somehow related to Response I return, it is in incorrect format, but what format should it be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
  public class ResponseMsg
    {
        public string status;
        public string name;
    }
```

---

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fname = String.Empty;
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];                    
                fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/UserImageUploads/" + file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(fname);
            }
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
       // context.Response.Write(fname);
      //  context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

        ResponseMsg r = new ResponseMsg
        {
            status = "success",
            name =fname
        };
       context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r));
    }
```